# Strange transaction interaction between insert and delete

Tags: postgresql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    foo INT
)
```

and I concurrently run inserts:

```
INSERT INTO table (foo) VALUES (?)
```

and deletes

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE ctid = (
    SELECT ctid FROM table -- <= call this query 'a'
    WHERE foo = ?
    ORDER BY id LIMIT 1)
RETURNING *
```

(ie, delete the row with the lowest `id` satisfying some criteria)

When the isolation level is set to Serializable, I will occasionally get `ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions` from the delete. This makes perfect sense: If an insert commits between when query 'a' happens and when the delete wants to commit, the result of query 'a' is no longer consistent.

What doesn't make sense is the behavior at lower isolation levels. What I would expect to happen is that query 'a' finds some `ctid`, the insert commits, then the row with that `ctid` is deleted. But what actually happens is that *no* row is deleted; the statement returns nothing even though the row is still there. (This still happens if I use `id` instead of `ctid`.)

Why is this happening?

Comment: The behaviour you are expecting is known as phantom read: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html

Comment: I think a test case demonstrating this would be useful...